# How to get from Wroclaw to city Nysa by bus?

Tags: buses, wroclaw

I searched on Google maps: is there some public transport from Wroclaw to Nysa? All I can find/see are routes by train(s). I like traveling by train(s), but also want to check is there some options to reach Nysa by bus?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.rome2rio.com/map/Wroc%C5%82aw/Nysa

Comment: FWIW I did some more web searching and it looks like to get from Wroclaw to Nysa by bus, you'd have to travel via Warsaw and use two separate bus companies. But I'm not posting this as a definitive answer because I am sure there are other people who know much more about bus travel in Poland than I do.

Comment: But the distance between Wroclaw and Nysa is approximately 90 kilometers, travel by train is very Ok approach, but I like to determine some other possibilities, i.e. in this case possibility to catch Nysa by bus...

Comment: If you change the destination in Rome2Rio, for example attempt a Wroclaw-Warsaw trip, you'll see it shows you bus routes when they are available. The fact it shows no routes for Wroclaw-Nysa is a good indicator that there's no easy route available on the main bus services (Flixbus and Polonus). I do see bus routes from Wroclaw to Opole or Brzeg, from which you might get a more local bus or shorter train ride to Nysa.